# Find the squares of all natural numbers <= 1000 ending in 3, 9, 6. (Use the map or collect method)

Tags: ruby

I don't know what needs to be done in the `.map` to knock out the last number 3, 6, 9. I try:

```
(
  (1..(999 % 10 == 3)).map { |x| x ** 2 } |
  (1..(999 % 10 == 6)).map { |x| x ** 2 } |
  (1..(999 % 10 == 9)).map { |x| x ** 2 }
).reduce(&:)
```

I understand that this is very wrong, but I am a beginner, can you help me!
Thank you!

Comment: Should the numbers end with 3, 9, 6? Or should the square numbers end with those digits?

Answer (score 3):

`(1..(999%10 == 3))` gets evaluated as:

```
(1..(999%10 == 3))
(1..(9 == 3))
(1..false)
```

Which gives `ArgumentError: bad value for range` because you apparently can't iterate from `1` to `false`.

You could use a range and [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#select-method):

```
(1..1000).select { |i| i % 10 == 3 }
#=> [3, 13, 23, 33, ..., 973, 983, 993]
```

You can then calculate the squares via:

```
(1..1000).select { |i| i % 10 == 3 }.map { |i| i ** 2 }
#=> [9, 169, 529, ..., 946729, 966289, 986049]
```

To combine the squares from 3, 6, and 9, you could use [`Array#+`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#2B-method):

```
(1..1000).select { |i| i % 10 == 3 }.map { |i| i ** 2 } +
(1..1000).select { |i| i % 10 == 6 }.map { |i| i ** 2 } +
(1..1000).select { |i| i % 10 == 9 }.map { |i| i ** 2 }
```

Or you could change the `select` statement to include those numbers right-away:

```
(1..1000).select { |i| i % 10 == 3 || i % 10 == 6 || i % 10 == 9 }
         .map { |i| i ** 2 }

# or

(1..1000).select { |i| [3, 6, 9].include?(i % 10) }.map { |i| i ** 2 }
```

---

Instead of filtering / selecting from a range of natural numbers, you could also *generate* this sequence using a custom [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerator.html):

```
three_six_nine = Enumerator.new do |y|
  0.step(by: 10) do |i|
    y << i + 3
    y << i + 6
    y << i + 9
  end
end

three_six_nine.take_while { |i| i <= 1000 } #=> [3, 6, 9, 13, 16, 19, ...]
              .map { |i| i ** 2 }           #=> [9, 36, 81, 169, 256, 361, ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

`(1..999).map{|x| x**2}.select{|x| [3,6,9].include?(x%10)}`
but for the record there is no square number ending with 3

Comment: I think it's the numbers ending in 3, 6, and 9, not their squares.

Comment: ok I understood he wanted "the squares ending in", but you might be right. Description of the problem is not crystal clear